# Convert linked image contain word file to embedded image html file

Tags: java, angular, ms-word

I am creating a web application for online exam. I have my questions in a MS word file that contains `image file(external source), shapes & graphs(ms word properties)` which are links of `.img/.jpg/.png/.gif` files stored in temp locations. When I copy these questions from file to editor, images does not come because these are links of image files.

I try this link [transform-linked-images-to-embedded-images](https://superuser.com/questions/294978/transform-linked-images-to-embedded-images)

But I can't see option `Edit Links to Files` in my MS word(2013, 2010)

Suggestions on how I can embed an image into html file and have it display in editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer of my question. First upload that file to `One Drive` then open and copy content from that file. Here is a link [Sign in and upload file](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-in/signin/)